# listing the local variables in irb

Tags: ruby, irb, local-variables

I am attempting to list all local variables and their values. This works in IRB:

```
local_variables.map {|var| "#{var} = " + local_variable_get(var).inspect
```

I would like to wrap this in a method, but when this code is placed inside a method, `local_variables` no longer points to the correct list of variables. Therefore, I tried some solutions along the lines of:

```
class Object
  def list_vars
    self.__send__(:binding).local_variables.map {|var| "#{var} = " + self.__send__(:binding).local_variable_get(var).inspect}
  end
end
```

However, it seems that the binding of the current object is different from `main`, which is used when calling `local_variables` directly.

Does `self.send(:binding)` change depending on what method `self` is in?

Comment: Sometimes you are writing `__send__`, and sometimes `send`. It is bad to be inconsistent.

Comment: You don't need `self.`.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you find any of them helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is really complicated and obfuscated. First, let's clean up your code a bit so that we can see more clearly what's going on. You don't need `self`, since it is the default receiver anyway. And you don't need `send`, because you already know the name of the method you want to call. Also, `Kernel#local_variables` uses the current `Binding` anyway. Also, typically, such methods which are supposed to by called without an explicit receiver and don't actually make use of `self` (e.g. like `puts` or `require`) are put into `Kernel`. So, your code is equivalent to the following:

```
module Kernel
  def list_vars
    local_variables.map {|var| "#{var} = " + binding.local_variable_get(var).inspect}
  end
end
```

Now we can immediately see the problem: you are reflecting on the local variables and the `Binding` of `list_vars` and not the place where it was called from! You need to pass the `Binding` into the method and use that instead:

```
module Kernel
  def list_vars(binding)
    binding.local_variables.map {|var| "#{var} = " + binding.local_variable_get(var).inspect}
  end
end

list_vars(binding)
```

Or, you could make it an instance method of `Binding`:

```
class Binding
  def list_vars
    local_variables.map {|var| "#{var} = " + local_variable_get(var).inspect}
  end
end

binding.list_vars
```

Comment: I ended up using the `binding_of_caller` gem, which enabled me to use the syntax of your second version, without needing to pass the binding in directly. Thank you for this clear answer!

Comment: Note that this gem works by basically breaking the encapsulation of the interpreter and ripping out its internals which necessarily ties it to a specific version of a specific interpreter. The gem contains versions for YARV and Rubinius, but will not work on JRuby, IronRuby, MagLev, MRuby,  Opal, MacRuby, or any other.

Comment: For the testing and debugging purposes I will end up using this, it will be fine, but it is something very important to note. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the binding into the method.

```
class Object
  def list_vars(b)
    a = 1 # This is only here to demonstrate. It's not necessary for it to work.
    b.local_variables.each do |var|
      puts "#{var} = " + b.local_variable_get(var).inspect
    end
  end
end

x = 1
list_vars(binding)

def foo
  z = 1
  list_vars(binding)
end

foo
```

Will output:

```
x = 1
z = 1
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `a = 1` to show that that does not affect the code, but for the purpose of presenting a working code, you don't need that line.

Comment: @sawa You're correct on both counts. Should have clarified I suppose.

Comment: Or alternatively OP could define `list_vars` as an instance method of `Binding` and then write `binding.list_vars` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Philip Hallstrom gives you a code that you can use to solve your problem, but does not answer your question. The real answer to your question is: Yes.